# Android Google Map, if I don't add MapFragment into Layout, my codes don't work. using map-v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to get my location without showing a map in activity! now, I can get the location add the mapFragment into Layout.

Here's my codes, please help me:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    // if don't add mMapFragment into Layout
    //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.parent, mMapFragment).commit();
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    // Doesn't work.
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "location changed!!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want location without map, you don't need google-maps.

Try this-
In your Manifest add these permissions-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then in your code use-

```
//get latitude & longitude
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();

//get a location listener
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
latitude = location.getLatitude();
longitude = location.getLongitude();
}


//get the address from lat and long.
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        int maxLines = address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();
        for (int i=0; i<maxLines; i++) {
            String addressStr = address.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
            builder.append(addressStr);
            builder.append(" ");
        }

        String finalAddress = builder.toString(); //This is the complete address.
        Log.d(TAG, "Final ADD: " + finalAddress);


    } catch (IOException e) {}
    catch (NullPointerException e) {}
```

Comment: There's a NullPointerException: in "Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);"

Comment: you have to get a location listener along with it. Edited the answer. A simple google search is easier than waiting for me to do the job!

Comment: I'm sad about that. I have do many searches with google, but I can't find out something wrong... What's more, now I have to use google map, and I find if I don't add MapFragment into Layout, it's listener can't make use.

Comment: This should solve your problem -  http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

The '*getLastKnownLocation*' return '*NULL*' because there is no last know location. To obtain the location you can register for location updates. But before requesting updates, your app must connect to location services. Start the updates by calling '*requestLocationUpdates*'. Do this in the '*onConnected()'* callback provided by Google client.

For more information, use this as your reference: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html